# How to know offsets within EDIT control to draw text?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, editbox, common-controls

I'm subclassing the [EDIT common control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456(v=vs.85).aspx) to add some special *placeholder text* behavior in the background and I'm curious how to know offsets to draw text within in?

`h` and `w` in this diagram:

[image]

Comment: Why not just call `SetWindowText`?

Comment: You can get that from `SendMessage(hedit, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rect)` The way you have marked it, some of the gap is from the font itself, but you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Maybe this isn't the case, but if you are about to reinvent another wheel, make sure to have a look at [EM_SETCUEBANNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639.aspx), and see if that doesn't suffice for your purposes.

Comment: @IInspectable: EM_SETCUEBANNER does not work on XP (or it is buggy, I should say.)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Thank you. It did the job! I wasn't aware that such message existed. Btw, you might want to post it as a separate answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`EM_GETRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761596(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the formatting rectangle for edit control. For example:

```
SendMessage(hedit, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rect)
```